# Differences in a video recorded with the same parameters but on different cameras

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, video, camera

I have a project in Unity where videos are recorded with the PC camera and then saved to the database. Regardless of the camera, I have defined that the first resolution less than 1000 wide that the camera accepts is used and that 15 fps or less is used. If your camera doesn't accept 15 fps or less, use the minimums.

I ran into the problem when I wanted to see how long the database would allow me to record the video without getting the error that it was too large. Here I saw that with the integrated camera of my laptop it allowed me to record videos of up to 6 minutes and 30 seconds, while if I recorded it with an external webcam the video can be a maximum of 4 minutes.

I was reviewing the videos recorded with the two cameras and I saw that the two videos are .mp4, recorded at 15 fps and that the resolution used by the integrated camera of my laptop is 960×720 and that of the webcam is 800×600. As I understand it, the video from the integrated camera should be shorter than the video from the webcam as it has a higher resolution, but nevertheless the database saves longer videos from the integrated camera, and from the webcam it gives me error with shorter videos.

Does anyone know if there are more parameters to take into account about the videos than the ones I mentioned, or any solutions for this?
I would like the videos to be able to have the same maximum length, regardless of the camera they are recorded with.

Comment: video compression?

Comment: What I would like to know is why with the webcam it leaves me less duration than with the integrated camera

Comment: this isnt really a programming issue, but it boils down to frame rate, compression, audio, its copmpression.. my iphone for example taking a like 30s video of my dog snoring like hes grinding concrete its many mb, gb even, do next to nothing to do it, and it can be reduced to a lot less.. with different compression even if all on the phone